"using Microsoft.JSInterop;" causes the side effects?
The official example of JavaScript interop functionality for RazorClassLibrary-CSharp template:
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace Company.RazorClassLibrary1;

public class ExampleJsInterop : IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask;

    public ExampleJsInterop(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        moduleTask = new (() => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
            "import", "./_content/Company.RazorClassLibrary1/exampleJsInterop.js").AsTask());
    }

    public async ValueTask<string> Prompt(string message)
    {
        var module = await moduleTask.Value;
        return await module.InvokeAsync<string>("showPrompt", message);
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (moduleTask.IsValueCreated)
        {
            var module = await moduleTask.Value;
            await module.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}

If we will remove using Microsoft.JSInterop; and replace references  IJSObjectReference and IJSRuntime to full qualified names:
namespace Company.RazorClassLibrary1;

public class ExampleJsInterop : IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task<Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask;

    public ExampleJsInterop(Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        moduleTask = new (() => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSObjectReference>(
            "import", "./_content/Company.RazorClassLibrary1/exampleJsInterop.js").AsTask());
    }

    public async ValueTask<string> Prompt(string message)
    {
        var module = await moduleTask.Value;
        return await module.InvokeAsync<string>("showPrompt", message);
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (moduleTask.IsValueCreated)
        {
            var module = await moduleTask.Value;
            await module.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}

we will get the following errors:

Argument type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type
'object?[]?'
at
jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSObjectReference>(
   "import", "./_content/Company.RazorClassLibrary1/exampleJsInterop.js").AsTask());



Argument type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type
'object?[]?'
at
csharp return await module.InvokeAsync<string>("showPrompt",
  message); 


What is that? The usage of "using Microsoft.JSInterop;" causes the side effects?
